# jmeter stop current iteration

Tags: iteration, jmeter, beanshell

I am facing the following problem:

I have multiple HTTP Requests in my testplan. 
I want every request to be repeated 4 times if they fail. 
I realized that with a BeanShell Assertion, and its already working fine.
My problem is, that I don't want requests to be executed if a previous Request failed 5 times,
BUT I also dont want the thread to end.

I just want the current thread iteration to end,
so that the next iteration of the thread can start again with the 1st request (if the thread is meant to be repeated).

How do I realize that within the BeanShell Assertion?
Here is just a short extract of my code where i want the solution to have

`badResponseCounter` is being increased for every failed try of the request, this seems to work so far. Afterwards, the variable gets resetted.

```
if (badResponseCounter = 5) {
        badResponseCounter = 0;
     // Stop current iteration
    }
```

I already checked the API, methods like setStopTest() or setStopThread() are given, but nothing for quitting the current iteration. I also need the preference "continue" in the thread group, as otherwise the entire test will stop after 1 single request failed. 
Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: Hello, I'd be interested in knowing how you were able to retry the sampler from your beanshell assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
ctx.setRestartNextLoop(true);
```

if the thread number is 2, i tried to skip. I get the below result as i expected (it does not call b-2). It does not kill the thread either.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the easiest way is using following combination:

1. [If Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) to check `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` and `badResponseCounter` variables
2. [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) Sampler as a child of If Controller configured to "Go to next loop iteration"