# How to skip remaining transactions and go to next iteration based on the value captured

Tags: jmeter

in jmeter script, is it possible to skip the remaining transactions and go to next iteration based on a captured value?

eg:

Thread Group1:
Sampler 1
Sampler 2
Sampler 3

whenever the value captured in Transaction 2 is 0, it should skip Transaction 3 and go to next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Right click Transaction 3 choose Insert Parent and add  [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) with condition checking that value isn't 0:

```
 ${jexl3("${value}" != "0")}
```

If you have saved value from transaction 2, just add Post Processor og Regular expression or JSON extractor depending on your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the following function. I have also provided the link to the previous answer from VINS.

```
ctx.setRestartNextLoop(true);
```

[jmeter stop current iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207638/jmeter-stop-current-iteration)